# .map inside call function react native

Tags: react-native

I want to send the values ​​in the DiscountPrice array to the setOrderDETAIL function as parameters. Since I call the function in .map, it calls as many functions as the item number, but I want to run this function 1 time. So I want to send the values ​​inside the DiscountPrice array to this.setOrderDETAIL function.

```
DiscountPrice.map((price)=>{
  this.UserCart.map((item)=>{
      return  this.setOrderDETAIL(item.Quantity, price, item.Quantity,item.ProductId,rsp.Order_Id);
  })
  })
```

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand you correctly, but it sounds to me like you a variable number of arguments stored in Discount Price that you want to pass into setOrderDetail.

If this is so, you can use argument destructuring using the `...` operator.

Comment: DiscountPrice : [], I want to send the values ​​in this variable to the setOrderDETAIL function. But since I made a .map, it calls the function more than once @QrowSaki

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
// assuming what you want is DiscountPrice = [arg1, arg2, arg3...]
DiscountPrice = ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
this.UserCart.map((item) => {
    return this.setOrderDETAIL(item.Quantity, item.ProductId, rsp.Order_Id, ...DiscountPrice);
});
```

Notice the `...` destructures the values in DiscountPrice so you can access them as individual arguments.

setOrderDETAIL would have the function signature like:

```
function setOrderDETAIL (quantity, productId, orderId, ...args) {
    // You can access DiscountPrice by doing args[0], args[1]...
}
```

Tell me if I misunderstood what you meant...(I feel like I might have. I will edit if appropriate.)

Comment: Again, the value comes as an array. It didn't work for me anyway, I was getting the array value. I need to get the values ​​inside the Array

Comment: Can you edit the question with what DiscountPrice looks like, what UserCart looks like, and what you expect the result to look like?

Comment: I just don't want the setOrderDETAIL function to be called for the number of items in the UserCart Array.